# Should you be checking if the fragment isAdded() whenever you call getParentFragment()?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments

The current version of Fragment deprecates `getFragmentManager()` in favor of `getParentFragmentManager()`, which is not nullable and throws an `IllegalStateException` instead. The same method says that you can check for `isAdded()` if you want to know whether the Fragment is currently added to an `activity/context`.

Does this mean that now you should be checking for `isAdded()` the same way you'd check if it's `!= null` before you call `getParentFragmentManager()`?

Or is the `IllegalStateException` a hint that it shouldn't even be null if you call it during the normal cycle of the fragment (since it will only call `onCreate()` after `onAttach()`).

Comment: If your fragment is designed properly it shouldn't perform any logic outside `onCreate` - `onDestroy` anyway so check isn't necessary. If you ever encounter this exception being thrown it'd indicate you forgot to unregister a listener or haven't canceled an async task.

Answer (score 2):

> Does this mean that now you should be checking for isAdded() the same
> way you'd check if it's != null before you call
> getParentFragmentManager()?

Looks like so. Before getFragmentManager() was nullable, so even if your call was completely safe (you called it after onAttach() and before onDetach()) the ide was showing you that this method can return null. Now you are responsible to call it only when you are sure that this fragment is added to parent fragment, and to check it you have the method isAdded().

Comment: I suppose that, as @Pawel commented above, this is only really necessary if the call is being done asynchronously, right? (which means you can't know whether it will be called after `onDestroy`)